# How can we pull dashboard data from quick sight to json format

Tags: amazon-quicksight, aws-quicksight-assets

Please help me pulling quicksigt chart or dashboard data in Json format. This is a project which iam not sure how to approach

I know we can pull data in csv or other formats but how can we do this in json format

Since iam not sure on the solution asking for help